# How to select rows from a hierarchical query filtering by descendant value in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, oracle11g, hierarchical

Given the table

```
ID       PARENT_ID      STRVAL      SUBTYPE     SUBVAL
0        null           Chicago     location    city
1        0              Best Buy    building    bestbuy
2        0              Walmart     building    walmart
3        0              Amazon      building    amazon
4        1              Macbook     object      macbook
5        2              Sausages    object      sausages
6        3              Macbook     object      macbook
7        3              Tupperware  object      tupperware
```

What I'm attempting to do is query this table and get all items from level 1 (the buildings), but what I need to do is filter this return set by returning those that have children containing a certain value.  The following query is what I have so far which returns Best Buy, Walmart, and Amazon

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT strval, parent_id, id
FROM stores
where LEVEL = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
START WITH parent_id = 0
)
```

What I would like to do is get a return where one of the descendants has a **subtype** of **object** and a **subval** of **macbook**, thus returning only **Best Buy** and **Amazon** from my query.  I'm not really sure where to go from here.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3f22a/2)

Comment: Is the `SUBTYPE` always in 1:1 relation to the levels in the tree structure? Is `object` always at level 2?

Comment: Object could be at level 3 in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reversing your `CONNECT BY` condition and starting with (i.e., `START WITH`) what you know:

```
SELECT DISTINCT strval, parent_id, id
FROM stores
where subtype = 'building'
CONNECT BY id = prior parent_id
START WITH subtype = 'object' and subval = 'macbook';
```

#### Update for more general question

In the comments, you asked what if the starting values aren't at the same level?

In that case, I'm afraid you'll have to look at the whole tree for each building and then filter.

I added this row to your test data:

```
insert into stores values (8, 4, 'Year','edition','2015');
```

Then, this query gives the answer:

```
WITH whole_tree AS
       (SELECT strval,
               parent_id,
               id,
               CONNECT_BY_ROOT(strval) building,
               SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH (subtype || ':' || subval, ',') PATH
        FROM   stores
        CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parent_id
        START WITH subtype = 'building')
SELECT distinct building
FROM   whole_tree
WHERE  PATH LIKE '%object:macbook%edition:2015%';
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I had been messing with reversing the CONNECT BY condition as you mentioned, but I hadn't though about setting my filter requirements in the START WITH section.  Thank you so much!

Comment: If I was to go one level deeper, where ID 4 of Macbook had a child item of subtype 'edition' and subvalue '2015', how could I go about filtering only those with subtype = 'object' and subval = 'macbook' but also a descendant's subtype of 'edition' and subvalue '2015'?

Comment: That's a different problem / question, requiring a completely different approach.  You need a different approach. Can you update your question or ask a new one?  Also, how big is the table?

Answer (score 1):

This join should give you macbook objects whose parents are buildings. Feel free to select columns you need only:

```
select *
from
(
select *
from stores
where subtype = 'object' 
and strval = 'Macbook'
) macs
join
(
select *
from stores 
where subtype = 'building'
) bld
on bld.id = macs.parent_id
```